# Docker rabbitmq doesn't work with RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER and RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I'm trying to run rabbitmq service with following configuration:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  rabbit-mq:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: 'test'
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'
    networks:
      monorepo:

  gateway:
    container_name: gateway
    environment:
      - APP_PORT=${GATEWAY_MS_PORT}
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - APP_NAME=monorepo-project
    ports:
      - ${GATEWAY_MS_PORT}:${GATEWAY_MS_PORT}
    networks:
      monorepo:

  user-microservice:
    container_name: user-microservice
    environment:
      - APP_PORT=${USER_MS_PORT}
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - APP_NAME=user-microservice
    ports:
      - ${USER_MS_PORT}:${USER_MS_PORT}
    networks:
      monorepo:
    depends_on:
      - user-microservice-db

  user-microservice-db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: user-microservice-db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${USER_MS_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${USER_MS_MYSQL_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - ${USER_MS_MYSQL_PORT}:${INTERNAL_DB_PORT}
    networks:
      monorepo:

networks:
  monorepo:
```

However, rabbitmq service give me the following error:

```
2022-04-03 12:59:28.937375+00:00 [info] <0.1164.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1164.0> (172.31.0.5:37026 -> 172.31.0.3:5672)

2022-04-03 12:59:30.941567+00:00 [info] <0.1171.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.1171.0> (172.31.0.5:37028 -> 172.31.0.3:5672)

2022-04-03 12:59:30.947123+00:00 [error] <0.1171.0> Error on AMQP connection <0.1171.0> (172.31.0.5:37028 -> 172.31.0.3:5672, state: starting):

2022-04-03 12:59:30.947123+00:00 [error] <0.1171.0> PLAIN login refused: user 'guest' - invalid credentials
```

Without default user and pass it works as expected. I've been searching for resolve last couple of days and have tried all suggestions from google.

Also, with my `RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER` and `RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS` I can login into managment plugin without any problem.

My .env file:

```
#RABBITMQ CONFIG
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=monorepo
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=monorepo
RABBITMQ_PORT=5672
RABBITMQ_URL=rabbitmq
RABBITMQ_QUEUE=users
```

Comment: Presumablky you're setting `$RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER` etc. in your `.env` file. What does that file look like?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but `default_pass` doesn't appear in /etc/rabbitmq.conf.
Solution for me was:

- delete environments
- `mkdir ./rabbit_config`
- `touch ./rabbit_config/rabbitmq.conf`
- put in `./rabbit_config/rabbitmq.conf`:

```
default_user = username
default_pass = password
```

- add to docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
      - ./rabbit_config/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/advanced.conf
```

- `docker-compose down` & `docker-compose up -d`

And `username`, `password` became valid credentinals.

P.S. On top of that, environment has just started work with no reason

Answer (score -1):

After 3.8 the environment variables that you are using are no longer supported.

> WARNING: As of RabbitMQ 3.9, all of the docker-specific variables listed below are deprecated and no longer used. Please use a configuration file instead; visit rabbitmq.com/configure to learn more about the configuration file. For a starting point, the 3.8 images will print out the config file it generated from supplied environment variables.

Use something like this in `/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json`:

```
{
 "rabbit_version": "3.9",
  {
   "name": "test12",
   "password_hash": "kI3GCqW5JLMJa4iX1lo7X4D6XbYqlLgxIs30+P6tENUV2POR,
   "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
   "tags": "administrator"
  }
 ],
 "vhosts": [
  {
   "name": "\/"
  },
 ],
 "permissions": [
  {
   "user": "local_jobs",
   "vhost": "\/",
   "configure": ".*",
   "write": ".*",
   "read": ".*"
  }
 ],
 "parameters": [],
 "policies": [],
 "queues": [],
 "exchanges": [],
 "bindings": []
}
```

Then add `./rabbitmq/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json:ro` to your volumes in your docker-compose.yaml.

The username and password is `test12`.

Comment: You refer to part of the documentation that listed deprecated environment variables. None of the variables listed there are used by OP.